# How much does each fraction contribute to decreasing a value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Say I have a value: 0.68. And this is decreased in half to 0.34 by multiplying it by $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$. Let's consider this decrease of $\frac{1}{2}$ as 100% of the decrease. So then we can consider the idea that $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ each contributed to this decrease, but in different magnitudes. I want to quantify the magnitude that each contributed to the decrease by assigning a percent.

If the total product contributes 100% to decreasing the value from 0.68 to 0.34, how can I get two percentages that represent how much the $\frac{3}{4}$ contributed and how much the $\frac{2}{3}$ contributed, respectively. Clearly the $\frac{2}{3}$ contributes more to the decrease of the value, but how much more?

All of my attempts have been squandered by, what I think is an error in, order of operations. If I pull out $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ and multiply the 0.68 individually, it doesn't make sense to pull it back in to see it's impact because I have just ruined my order of operations.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted?

Comment: consider it such a kind of welcome! don't worry for that, you could maybe show better what you have tried.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  How do you quantify "how much" each factor contributes in the first place?  Rather than multiplying by $\frac{3}{4}$ and then by $\frac{2}{3}$, what if you multiplied by them in the other order as $\frac{2}{3}$ and *then* by $\frac{3}{4}$?  Once you phrase your question precisely with appropriate definitions, I expect the answer will be immediately apparent.

Comment: @JMoravitz I tried to add more to indicate what I mean. In general: if I decrease a number in half by multiplying it by two other numbers. How can I see what percent each of the two numbers contributed to that decrease? i.e. if the decrease is in half, maybe the $\frac{2}{3}$ contributes 60% and the $\frac{3}{4}$ contributes 40% to the full decrease. (I made up those numbers)

Comment: One possible interpretation... we have an initial amount, lets call it $A_0$.  We then multiply by our "first factor," for now we'll say that's $\frac{3}{4}$, and then call the result $A_1$.  We'll call the "contribution" of this first operation $A_0-A_1$.  Similarly, we'll multiply $A_1$ by our second factor to get $A_2$ and call the contribution made here to be $A_1-A_2$.  In that case, we'd get the contribution of $\frac{3}{4}$ to be $.17$ and of $\frac{2}{3}$ to be $.17$ as well.  Applying the factors in the other order changes these values.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, that is true. But clearly they don't contribute equally to decreasing the value from 0.68 to 0.34, since $\frac{2}{3}$ decreases 0.68 more than $\frac{3}{4}$, right?

Comment: Another possible interpretation, we look at this using logarithms and we look at the ratio $\frac{\ln(3/4)}{\ln(3/4)+\ln(2/3)}\approx 0.415$ compared to $\frac{\ln(2/3)}{\ln(3/4)+\ln(2/3)}\approx 0.585$.  Again... until you adequately define what it is you want to look at it is not clear what you want.

Comment: "*but* **clearly** *they don't contribute equally...since $\frac{2}{3}$ decreases $0.68$ more than $\frac{3}{4}$, right?*"  No... it is *not* clear at all.  In my first interpretation above, they *do* contribute equally (*in the order listed*).

Comment: @JMoravitz I think your explanation of $\frac{\ln(3/4)}{\ln(3/4)+\ln(2/3)}\approx 0.415$ compared to $\frac{\ln(2/3)}{\ln(3/4)+\ln(2/3)}\approx 0.585$, is what I'm looking for. Can you explain the source of this, or why it works?

Comment: @JMoravitz Good idea the logarithm I was also think to a way such that

Comment: If we have a summation, $x+y+z=S$ and we want to know what the ratio is of $x$ compared to the sum, we would look at $\frac{x}{S}$.  This has the nice property that $\frac{x}{S}+\frac{y}{S}+\frac{z}{S}=1$.  You could attempt to do similarly by using multiplication instead of addition, but it becomes unclear how you would replace the division.  Instead, using logarithms, letting $x\times y\times z = S$ we would have $\ln(x\times y\times z)=\ln(S)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)+\ln(z)$, and so we get a similar situation as before with $\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(S)}+\frac{ln(y)}{\ln(S)}+\frac{\ln(z)}{\ln(S)}=1$

Comment: The short answer of why logarithms/exponentiation is sometimes a convenient way to look at things... is that logarithms "turn multiplication into addition", and exponentiation "turns addition into multiplication."  (*there is more precise language that can be used to explain what exactly is going on in later abstract algebra courses*).  Since we have an intuitive idea of what we want if it were addition, then we could use that to our advantage after making the appropriate changes.  Keep in mind though, that this is *not* technically the same "proportion" as normal addition proportions are.

Comment: @jchaykow Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi the answer I saw as most applicable was given as a comment from JMoravitz so I haven't accepted any answe because it hasn't been posted as one yet

Comment: @jchaykow The choice is completely up to you of course, you can accept or not, the important think is that you are aware about this possibility. Bye

Answer (score 2):

The amount in the decrease in a value $n$ by multiplying by $\frac{3}{4}$ given by:
$$n\bigg(1-\frac{3}{4}\bigg)=n-\frac{3n}{4}= \frac{n}{4}$$
After this decrease, remains a value of $\frac{3n}{4}$.  Multiplying now by $\frac{2}{3}$ decreases this remaining value by:
$$\bigg(\frac{3n}{4}\bigg)\bigg(1-\frac{2}{3}\bigg)=\frac{3n}{4}-\frac{6n}{12}=\frac{9n-6n}{12}=\frac{3n}{12}=\frac{n}{4}$$
Therefore, they both decrease the value by the same amount, which makes sense.  If you have $n$ portions and you remove $\frac{1}{n}$ of it, you end up with ${n-1}$ portions.  So, you can successively multiply by $\frac{n-1}{n}$ with decreasing $n$ and remove the same amount each time.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have

$$0.68\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{4}=\frac12\cdot0.68=0.34$$

we should evaluate the contribute of $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$ for $\frac12$ but the two moltiplicative coefficient are correlated and act together.

To better see that fact we can consider

$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{3}{4}=\left(1-\frac13\right)\left(1-\frac14\right)=1-\frac13-\frac14+\frac1{12}$$

thus
$$0.68\cdot\frac{2}{3} \cdot\frac{3}{4}=0.68\cdot\left(1-\frac13\right)\left(1-\frac14\right)=0.68-\frac13\cdot 0.68-\frac14\cdot 0.68+\frac1{12}\cdot 0.68$$

then

- the reduction for $\frac23$ as it was applied singularly is$-\frac13\cdot 0.68=-0.22\bar6$
- the reduction for $\frac34$ as it was applied singularly is $-\frac14\cdot 0.68=-0.170$
- the increment for $\frac23$ and $\frac34$ acting together is$\frac1{12}\cdot 0.68=0.05\bar6$

More in general, if we indicate with $A_0$ the initial amount, with $A_f$ the final amount, with $\Delta A=A_0-A_f$ the variation and with $r_1=1-c_1$ and $r_2=1-c_2$ the reduction factors we have

$$A_f= A_0\cdot r_1 \cdot r_2= A_0\cdot (1-c_1) \cdot (1-c_2)=A_0-c_1A_0-c_2A_0+c_1c_2A_0\\\implies \Delta A=A_0-A_f=A_0(c_1+c_2-c_1c_2)\\\implies \frac{\Delta A}{A_0}=c_1+c_2-c_1c_2$$

As suggested and explained by [JMoravitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/179297/jmoravitz), by logarithms it is possible to separate the two contributes and assign a petange to each one separetely.